# how to select rows from a data frame using a condition from two columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am doing differentially gene expression analysis and have a data frame with p.values that are <0.05 for both conditions (columns). I will like to filter the p.values that are <0.05 for one column with the condition that it would not be <0.05 on the second column.

```
df
    row.names        padj.co         padj.c2
1   1.1.1.m1    5.789924e-02    1.745791e-02
2   1.1.100.m1  5.875004e-14    3.459149e-14
3   1.1.1000.m1 3.511273e-11    4.045594e-11
```

Any ideas will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please state in the original post where `decideTests` comes from.

Comment: just deleted the second example that was misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
df[df$padj.co < 0.05 & df$padj.c2 >= 0.05, ]
```

I don't think I understand your second question without more background.

Comment: Sorry the second question was to give another example of the data I need to filter which gives the same results. But that one you just wrote works perfect. Thanks